# Ghostscript Converting PDF to PNG With Wrong Output Size

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript, image-conversion

I'm using the following Ghostscript command to convert an 8.5" x 17.00" (2:1) PDF to a PNG:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=png16m -sNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="C:\output.png" -r120 -q -dBATCH "C:\input.pdf"
```

This command has worked well for me in the past, but with a given set of input PDFs it is adding whitespace to the bottom of the outputted PNG. The PNGs are coming out at 1080x2460 (18:41).

I also tried sDEVICE=pngalpha and it had the same result.

The image below shows the source PDF on the left, and the output PNG on the right:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what might cause this?

Comment: Most likely the PDF has a TrimBox or CropBox and you have not asked GS to use it. Its impossible to say wihtout seeing the PDF file, the PNG doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you @KenS. I will check with the folks who prepared the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the comments by @KenS, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657458/obey-the-mediabox-cropbox-in-pdf-when-using-ghostscript-to-render-a-pdf-to-a-png), I learned of these Ghostscript flags:

```
-dUseTrimBox
-dUseCropBox
-dUseArtBox
-dPDFFitPage
```

When I include `-dUseCropBox` in the command, it works correctly:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=png16m -dUseCropBox -sNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="C:\output.png" -r120 -q -dBATCH "C:\input.pdf"
```

Source: [Obey the MediaBox/CropBox in PDF when using Ghostscript to render a PDF to a PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657458/obey-the-mediabox-cropbox-in-pdf-when-using-ghostscript-to-render-a-pdf-to-a-png)

Comment: You can't use **both** of them, they are mutually exclusive, you can use **either** the TrimBox (-dUseTrimBox) **or** the CropBox (-dUseCropBox). You shouldn't set both.....